# How to download route from one place to another of google map in pdf?

Tags: google-maps, pdf, google-maps-api-3

i had calculated route for 2 places using directionsRenderer(); now i need to download the route in pdf format . is it possible. my code for route map is

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapp"),myOptions);

latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(glat,glon);

$('#mapDiv1').modal({closeClass: "mapCloseImg"});

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("panel"));
var request = {
  origin: acity,
  destination:latlng,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
});
```